# Permutation implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

permutation_str works fine but permutation_arr doesn't output the correct answer. I don't see why the two functions are generating different outputs given the fact that they have the same implementation. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
def permutation_arr(res, arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        print(res)
    
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        res.append(arr[i])
        permutation_arr(res, arr[:i] + arr[i+1:])
        res = res[:-1]

permutation_arr([], [1,2,3])

def permutation_str(res, str):
    if len(str) == 0:
        print(res)
    
    for i in range(len(str)):
        res = res + str[i]
        permutation_str(res, str[:i] + str[i+1:])
        res = res[:-1]

permutation_str("", "123")
```

Comment: The difference is that `res.append(arr[i])` changes the contents of the list, whereas `res = res + str[i]` creates a new string with the different contents. I suggest stepping through your code with https://pythontutor.com/ to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do is remove the last element using `pop` after you are done with a recursive call. Don't create a copy again. `pop` won't throw an empty list exception because you are doing it after `append`. The res[:-1] creates a different list and you don't want to change the list when passing along in your recursive calls, you'd want the same list to be passed all along the recursion.

```
def permutation_arr(res, arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        print(res)
    
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        res.append(arr[i])
        permutation_arr(res, arr[:i] + arr[i+1:])
        res.pop()

permutation_arr([], [1,2,3])
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

arrays are mutable... so that res you keep appending is always the same

try this instead

```
def permutation_arr(res, arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        print(res)
    
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        res.append(arr[i])
        # send a copy of res instead of res
        permutation_arr(res[:], arr[:i] + arr[i+1:])
        res = res[:-1]

permutation_arr([], [1,2,3])
```